# How to close multiple connections in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In trying to create two databases (using mongoose) in the same index.js, I created multiple connections using the `mongoose.createConnection()` method. As a result I can't use the `mongoose.connection.close()` method to close the connections because it only works if you use the `mongoose.connection()` method in creating your connection.

Does anyone know how I can't close my connections I created with `mongoose.createConnection()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.